# Load data to a Select Dropdown menu int a dynamically populated Partial View

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm loading a partial view dynamically with Javascript into a DIV:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Details","User")',
        data: { id: userId},
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
        $("#user-details").show().html(data);})
```

When displayed I would like to populate a few drop down menus for a user to make a selection.
Lets say I want to populate a list of "UserCategories"

So on success of ajax call above I do:

```
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetUserCategories","User")',function(data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {

                    $("#userCategories-list").append(
                        $("<option></option>").text(item.Name).val(item.Id)
                    );
                });
            });
```

The UserCategories list isn't being populated.

I assume it's because the UserDetails source html that contains the UserCategories drop down menu is rendered dynamically and not shown on the page ?

How can I access and populate my "userCategories-list" drop down menu that's displayed with an ajax call and which HTML/control name I cannot see when I look at the page source/Firebug ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the code stopping? Is the second AJAX call getting fired? Is the `each` statement getting called? Is the function in the `each` getting called?

Comment: I had an alert(item.Name) for testing before .append and it triggers just fine. Popups show up with the correct data. It just seems that the "userCategories-list" isn't found, therefore the items aren't appended to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say for sure, but my guess is that your partial view isn't a part of the browsers DOM when your list-creating function is called. In fact, I don't see any code that loads your partial into the browser for rendering.

Have you tried debugging with firebug or the [chrome debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview)? You can set breakpoints in your functions and see what is actually going on.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Details","User")',
        data: { id: userId},
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) { 
            $("#partialContainer").html(data);
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetUserCategories","User")',function(listData) {
                $.each(listData, function (key, item) {
                    $("#userCategories-list").append(
                        $("<option></option>").text(item.Name).val(item.Id)
                    );
                }); //each
            )); //getJson
        } //success anon function
  }); //$.ajax
```

Comment: Also, there's a missing semicolon on your append function `$("<option...`), that could be screwing things up. Gotta be careful with those!

Comment: edited again, changed data to listData in the inner ajax call.

Comment: and, fixed a missing parenthesis in getJSON.

Comment: Hmmm.. it doesn't seem much different from my code. Btw, that semi colon after val(item.Id) doesn't belong there

Comment: It's working now. I'm not sure exactly what the difference is. I think I was getting messed up by GET caching.
Thanks.